# Is there a way to control and automate snapshot generation for projects in SonarQube 6.3?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube6.3

According to Sonarqube documentation: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Concepts 
A snapshot is generated for each analysis. Is there any way available to control this versioning and the given time for the snapshot generation. If yes, then I would like to automate the naming of snapshot generation.

Further explanation: I would like to have given time for a snapshot equal to say 2 weeks and give it a name like: "119.0 Sprint" and then for the next snapshot generation, I want that sonarqube names it as "120.0 Sprint".

Any helpful documentation or tutorial would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To update the version string that's shown in SonarQube, you should update its source: your `sonar-project.properties`, `pom.xml` or other document used to feed the basic analysis values such as project key, sources directory and so on.

This *should* be done externally to SonarQube, although you *can* attach such values to snapshots via the SonarQube UI after the face.